# How to create a array of form on DHTMLX

Tags: forms, dhtmlx

I need to create more forms on-the-fly. This example creates two forms dynamically, it works, but not in the events section.

```
<div id="form_container" style="width:280px;height:250px;"></div>

<script>
var array_form = array_grid = new Array();

formStructure_modBase = [
    {type: "block", blockOffset: 0, list: [
        {type:"input",label:"",name:"id_base"}, 
        {type:"container",name:"grid_base",label:"",inputWidth:400,inputHeight:150},    
        {type:"button",name:"button_base",value:"SAVE"},
    ]},
];      


for(var ii=0;ii<=1;ii++)
{
    //create array form 
    array_form[ii] = new dhtmlXForm("form_container",formStructure_modBase);
    array_form[ii].setItemValue("id_base",ii);
    //events (DOESN'T WORK!)
    array_form[ii].attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id){
        if(id=="button_base") alert("Save Form "+ii);
    }); 
    //create grid                           
    array_grid[ii] = new dhtmlXGridObject(array_form[ii].getContainer("grid_base"));
    array_grid[ii].setImagePath("../../codebase/imgs/");
    array_grid[ii].setHeader("Num,Des");
    array_grid[ii].setInitWidthsP("50,50");
    array_grid[ii].setColAlign("center,left");
    array_grid[ii].setColTypes("ro,ed");  
    array_grid[ii].setSkin("dhx_web");
    array_grid[ii].init();                                  
}                               
</script>
```

This code works properly, but the number of forms is not known at design time.

```
array_form[0].attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id){
        if(id=="button_base") alert("Save Form 0");
    }); 
array_form[1].attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id){
        if(id=="button_base") alert("Save Form 1");
    });
```

How can I handle events correctly?
Thanks.

---

UPDATE
This seems to work properly:

```
..
..
//create array form 
array_form[ii] = new dhtmlXForm("form_container",formStructure_modBase);
array_form[ii].setItemValue("id_base",ii);
//events (WORKS)
addEvent(ii);
//create grid                           
array_grid[ii] = new dhtmlXGridObject(array_form[ii].getContainer("grid_base"));
..
..

function addEvent(form_num) 
{
    array_form[form_num].attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id){
        if(id=="button_base") alert("Save Form "+form_num);
    });     
}
```

Comment: Update.
this seems to work properly:

...
//add event
addEvent(ii);